# Tasks Combining by groups into a single group

Tags: c#, .net, task, .net-4.5, async-await

Assuming I have all of the classes implementing `IGenerator`

```
List<IGenerator> generators = new List<IGenerator> { new Jane1Generator(), new Jane2Generator(), new JohnGenerator() };
```

And

```
public interface IGenerator
{
    string GetFirstName();
    Task<List<Items>> Generate();
}
```

So grouping `generators` by `GetFirstName()` will put `Jane1` and `Jane2` in the same category. How can I combine the Tasks for `Jane1` and `Jane2` into a single Task, and keep `John` separate. I want to combine the results of both Janes into a single List.

```
        foreach (var groupedByName in generators.GroupBy(i => i.GetFirstName()))
        {
            //Combine Tasks of Jane1 & Jane2
            //give me a new Task that's is the sum of Jane1 & Jane2 tasks.
            //almost like List<Items>.Join(AnotherList) wrapped with a Task, so I can wait for both Tasks and Get combined Results instead.
        }
```

so If I create a `List<Task<List<Items>>> tasks = new List<Task<List<Items>>>();`
I want `tasks` list to contain only two elements. one would be the combine tasks of Jane1&Jane2 and the other just John, so I can do

```
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  Console.Write("Done");
```

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need the Janes together when in the end, you just want to wait until everything is complete?

Comment: I just want to combine Janes results together. I am joining the results into a different list, and I want that list to contain only two elements. Janes and John Generated Items.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with `GroupBy` to group all of the generators by name.

Then select out those groups into the needed information, namely the name and the items.

To get a task representing all of the items for that group you can use `Select` to get a sequence of all of the items for each generator in the group.  Giving that to `WhenAll` gives us a task that will be done when all of the generators finish.  We can then add a continuation to that task that combines all of the items together into a single list.

```
var groups = generators.GroupBy(gen => gen.GetFirstName())
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Name = group.Key,
        Items = Task.WhenAll(group.Select(gen => gen.Generate()))
            .ContinueWith(t => t.Result.SelectMany(items => items).ToList())
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tasks.Add(Task<IEnumerable<Items>>.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(results.ToArray(), 
myTasks => 
{
  var newList = new List<Items>();
  foreach (var i in results)
   {
     newList.AddRange(i.Result);
   }
   return DoSomething(newList.AsEnumerable());
}));
```

where `results` is the list of my groups items by their firstName.